# How to retrieve all Template namespace links from articles in a Wikipedia category

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Say I have some category from Wikipedia. There are some articles that are in this category. If you open each article one by one, some of these articles will have one or more Template namespace elements embedded in it. I'd like to retrieve a list of all Template namespace elements embedded in the articles in a category.

It will be good to also allow articles from child categories to be included.

How can I do this with the Wikipedia API, or are there other ways of doing it, other than to use a scripting language to retrieve the HTML from the front end of each wikipedia article and extract those templates?

Comment: You won't get template names from HTML. You have to get wikitext and look for {{<Templatename>}} strings. Alternately you can get  for one article all templates used with Mediawiki action API for one page : [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=templates&titles=English%20language)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of templates used by a page with the [prop=templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Btemplates) API endpoint.

You can also use that on top of a [generator list](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) of [categorymembers](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bcategorymembers). Here is an example query:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=templates&generator=categorymembers&tllimit=500&gcmtitle=Category%3AAnimals&gcmlimit=500

And here is the same query limited to templates from the Template namespace (10), excluding transclusion of pages from the main or Module namespace for example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=templates&tlnamespace=10&generator=categorymembers&tllimit=500&gcmtitle=Category%3AAnimals&gcmlimit=500